# Как лучше перевести название гимна "Abide with Me"?

Tags: перевод, стилистика

Это религиозный гимн середины 19-го века. Как бы вы перевели название, чтобы передать стлилистику?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abide_with_Me

Update: чтобы был сразу понятен стиль и контекст, вот две заключительные строки:

> Heaven's morning breaks, and earth's vain shadows flee;
>
> In life, in death, O Lord, abide with me.

Comment: Что-то вроде "оставайся верным мне" или "оставайся со мной".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, название обычно не переводят отдельно от текста. Поэтому, как в русском (поэтическом!) тексте будет звучать "abide", таким оно должно быть и в названии.

Во-вторых, это отсылка к библии. Поэтому имеет смысл обратиться к её русским переводам. Однако тут есть проблемка: выходит либо "**облязи со мной**", либо "**останься со мной**". При этом вряд ли одно или другое будет употребимо в поэтическом переводе (см. п. 1).

Итого мы имеем: полный поэтический перевод проще сделать на "**Пребудь со мной**", хотя это будет не совсем верно, но если речь идет просто о названии, лучше все же держаться синодального перевода: "**Останься со мной**".

Comment: I belive translation as "не оставь меня[, Господи]" much  better fits context,  time (!) and general sense of this phrase...

Comment: @Sergey It badly fits iambus. Neither it suits in Bible context.

Answer (score 4):

I believe "Пребудь со мной" is the standard translation. It means basically the same as "оставайся со мной", but has some poetic flavour.

Comment: Standard translation of this particular phrase? Can you think of any examples?

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs, of this particular title. It's a fairly well known hymn, and I think I've seen it with this translation. It must be googleable.

Comment: Из сборника евангельских песнопений (на этой странице такое обращение к Господу несколько раз встречается):

https://books.google.ru/books?id=9kFlM06kqwEC&hl=ru&pg=PT571&img=1&zoom=3&ots=JfRV2Be8iN&sig=ACfU3U2S9SMHuAP5DT3YC5EBV0jzB5ub5Q&w=1280

Comment: @Zeus I'll google harder :)

Comment: @Alex_ander broken link

Comment: Try this one (I've uploaded it to image host): http://i78.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0801/2a/1a111e2a73f7277b5fd361ad5387eb2a.png

Answer (score 2):

Хотя мне понравилось "пребудь", я бы сказала "не покидай меня". Звучит не так архаично.
Как в выражении "**не оставь меня, Господи**" (своими молитвами)
Вообще, отрицательная повелительная форма смотрится и звучит мягче в обращении к Богу, нежели "пребудь","останься". Впрочем,перевод всегда субъективен.

Comment: A "abide with me", по-вашему, архаично не звучит?

Comment: А второй даунвотец где?

Comment: Вам еще нужно что-то откомментировать? "Не покидай меня" - это что-то из области романса. Выглядит как на корове седло.

Comment: Спасибо,  Вы так любезны, приму к сведению.

Comment: А комментировать надо всегда.